# How can I set the value of a text box widget added to a piece of whamlet using fvInput?

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I have added a widget to a piece of whamlet using `#{fvInput idView}`. This displays an empty text box, but I would like the text box to have text in it. With HTML it would be `<input type=text value="Type here">`. How can I do this with `fvInput`?